# Why use GWT and what is it better then other Javascript UI frameworks ?

Tags: java, javascript, gwt

I'm building a REST web server and I need to choose a UI framework which would work well with Java ee 6 REST web services. I want the UI to be very efficient and have all the AJAX and JQuery capabilities like loading the data from the server without refreshing the page. New data gets added often so I need the UI to display new data every 3-5 seconds ... drag and drop feature etc.

I've been reading up on GWT and here are my questions:

- GWT compiles the Java code to Javascript right ? Obviously Javascript is not good for SEO but does using GWT makes it Google SEO friendly ?
- Performance vise - is GWT quicker then using Javascript tools like redis, JQueryUI or AJAX or one of many other javascript UI frameworks or they all are the same ?
- GWT also supports server side coding in the GWT project itself correct ? Is there a benefit of writing server side code in the GWT project then building it in a different project or is this a silly question and it does not really matter where I write the server side code ?

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not a Recommendation Engine](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128562/177538) and [Stack Overflow is not your personal research assistant](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553/177538)

Comment: *Obviously Javascript is not good for SEO* — Err, JavaScript is a tool. Using it isn't bad for SEO. Using it badly can be.

Comment: *Performance vise* — again, depends on what you do with it.

Comment: *Javascript tools like redis, JQueryUI or AJAX or one of many other javascript UI frameworks* — Redis is a key/value store, Ajax is something you can do with JavaScript, I wouldn't call either a "JavaScript tool" or a "UI framework".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> GWT compiles the Java code to Javascript right ? Obviously Javascript is not good for SEO but does using GWT makes it Google SEO friendly ?

I think that there is no solution, because there is no problem. With GWT you can make web applications not web pages.

> Performance vise - is GWT quicker then using Javascript tools like redis, JQueryUI or AJAX or one of many other javascript UI frameworks or they all are the same ?
>   There are many aspect of the performance of GWT projects.

1. Loading time of you application.

   Divide your application in logical parts, when a user wants to  a particular part of the application, it should load only the required resources only. its other parts will  loaded on demand. So, More or less a design issue you will have to deal/manage with.
2. Rendering time for widgets, views, etc.

   GWT creates its own DOM. In the JQuery usage existing HTML and is enhanced upon.
3. Data transfer time to/from server and client.

   No significant difference.

> GWT also supports server side coding in the GWT project itself correct ? Is there a benefit of writing server side code in the GWT project then building it in a different project or is this a silly question and it does not really matter where I write the server side code ?

GWT support many ways to send/receive data from/to server. This does not force you to write your server side code in your GWT project itself. But, If you choose so, you will have the shared model classed and other utility classes in your reach on both client and server. You can write your code in a defferent project too, But in that case, you will have to implement some way to manage the share code(such as, build tools).

The Biggest gain:
With GWT, you can build your applications using a real object-oriented language and take advantage of Java tools like Eclipse that are already available.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm trying to build a web a web site with Ajax type functionality to it for a quicker load and no page refreshes. Since you said GWT is used to build web application and not web pages. Do you think it will be a bad idea to build a website using just GWT and that I should be using Struts 2 to build the website ?

Comment: In my opinion, you  should go with GWT as front end and Struts or Spring framework in the back end. There should not be any integration Issue.

Comment: I'm using Java ee 6 so I don't have to use Spring Framework I guess ... am I correct ? I thought Struts was a UI framework and not a backend framework and helps building web pages ? So you saying I should use GWT as front end and use Java EE 6 framework as backend ?

Comment: Yes, You are right. This will be a good choice. One thing to have in mind when designing a solution. Keep things simple and small. break your programs/modules in small peaces.

Comment: Thanks heaps for you answer. helped a lot :)